# Centrar Mapa en iOS en Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación de turismo en la cual hay varias cabañas, lugares para comer y visitar en este caso cada una tiene un boton que va a un único mapa en el cual hay marcadores para mostrar la ubicación, y necesito que el centro del mapa cargue dependiendo del botón que fue presionado. agrego el codigo del mapController.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class mapController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myMapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapTajMahal()

    }

    func mapTajMahal()
    {
        //Taj Mahal Coordinates: 27.175015, 78.042139

        // Coordinates
        let tajLat:CLLocationDegrees = -39.849254
        let tajLong:CLLocationDegrees = -71.994215

        let tajCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tajLat, longitude: tajLong)

        let mocho = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.849152, longitude: -71.943082)
        let aitue = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.849581, longitude: -71.945078)
        let rucapillan = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.833403841808995, longitude:-72.07239013854979)
        let c_elportal = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.848834,longitude: -71.937480)
        let c_los_alamos = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.851652, longitude: -71.931052)
        let c_lago_neltume = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.77999, longitude: -71.95708)
        let c_peumayen = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.848467, longitude: -71.938013)
        let domos = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.850835, longitude: -71.940623)
        let patagonia = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.858635, longitude: -71.918520)
        let madero = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.858635, longitude: -71.918520
        )

        //Span
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.2
        let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.2
        let tajSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: longDelta)

        let tajRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: tajCoordinate, span: tajSpan)

        myMapView.setRegion(tajRegion, animated: true )

        let tajAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        tajAnnotation.title = "Neltume"
        tajAnnotation.subtitle = "She walks in beauty"
        tajAnnotation.coordinate = tajCoordinate


        let mochoannotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        mochoannotation.title = "Mocho Neltume"
        mochoannotation.coordinate = mocho

        let aitueanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        aitueanotation.title = "Aitue Expediciones"
        aitueanotation.coordinate = aitue

        let rucapillananotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        rucapillananotation.title = "Rafting Excursiones Restaurant Hostal Cabañas Rucapillan"
        rucapillananotation.coordinate = rucapillan

        let c_elportalanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_elportalanotation.title = "Cabañas el Portal"
        c_elportalanotation.coordinate = c_elportal

        let c_los_alamosanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_los_alamosanotation.title = "Cabañas los Alamos"
        c_los_alamosanotation.coordinate = c_los_alamos

        let c_lago_neltumeanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_lago_neltumeanotation.title = "Cabañas Lago Neltume"
        c_lago_neltumeanotation.coordinate = c_lago_neltume

        let c_peumayenatonation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_peumayenatonation.title = "Cabañas Peumayen"
        c_peumayenatonation.coordinate = c_peumayen

        let domosanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        domosanotation.title = "Cabañas Karü Domos del Fuy"
        domosanotation.coordinate = domos

        let patagoniaanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        patagoniaanotation.title = "Cabañas Patagonia Mawida"
        patagoniaanotation.coordinate = patagonia

        let maderoanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        maderoanotation.title = "Restaurante Refugio del Madero"
        maderoanotation.coordinate = madero

        myMapView.addAnnotation(mochoannotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(aitueanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(rucapillananotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_elportalanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_los_alamosanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_lago_neltumeanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_peumayenatonation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(patagoniaanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(maderoanotation)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el código ya tienes el `setRegion(_:)` que es precisamente para eso pero el problema puede ser que lo estás haciendo en el `viewDidLoad`. 
Prueba a llamar a la función en el `viewDidAppear` para dar tiempo al mapa en cargar. Si no funciona, utiliza el delegado del mapView que te permite saber cuando ha acabado de cargar el mapa y entonces ahí centras el mapa con `setRegion(_:)`

Comment: hola el mapa si muestra el centro sin problema, el tema es que hay varios botones que llevan al mismo mapa y necesito que desde cada botón cargue el mapa centrado en una ubicación distinta =).

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer entonces es un `viewController` que solo tenga el mapa, al que le pasas unas coordenadas. Entonces, cuando pulses el botón de cada posición, instancias el mapa pasando las coordenadas del centro y listo

Comment: Con Storyboard segue se puede enviar la información para que cargue cada botón el mismo mapa y distintos centros?  me puedes ayudar con el código?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente puedes agregar una función algo asi:

```
func centerInPosition(position:CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    map.setCenterCoordinate(position, animated: true)
}
```

y la llamas:

```
centerInPosition(tajAnnotation.coordinate)
```

tendrías que tener un arreglo o un diccionario con los MKPointAnnotation para poder saber a cual ir.